# Why is the music of Studio Ghibli movies so similar?

Tags: music, studio-ghibli

The Studio Ghibli movies music seems to have various spinoffs of the same music across the movies.

Why was that music chosen? Is there any importance relevance or meaning into it? What is the name of the music? The music I am talking about can be heard in all movies. For instance in the first seconds of Majo no Takkyuubin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Especially if you are focusing on the movies directed by Hayao Miyazaki, the reason the soundtracks sound similar is going to be that most of them were composed by the same person: [**Joe Hisaishi**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Hisaishi)

[image: Joe Hisaishi]

Joe has a distinctive musical style, just like many composers do (for example, John Williams or Hans Zimmer are Western equivalents), and you can hear it even outside of his Ghibli works. Also, because the films all have similar emotional and narrative tones, it makes sense that he would try to instill similar feelings in the soundtracks for them.